# Why is my segmented control not showing in my view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c-2.0

My segmented control in the xib view doesn't show up when I run the application. Please help me!

m File

```
- (IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged{
  switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
          self.carImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];
      break;
    case 1:
          self.carInfo.text = @"Segmented 1 selected.";
      break;
      case 3:
          self.carImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"];
          break;
    default:
       break;
   } 
}
@end
```

h File

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *carImage;
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
IBOutlet UILabel *carInfo;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *carImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *carInfo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

- (IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged;

@end
```

Comment: The code you showed doesn't help diagnose the problem. Are you sure you have the control added in your xib? I..don't even know what questions to ask here. Can you show a screenshot of the xib?

Comment: Have you set properly the referencing outlets in Xib? I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: @jtbandes, yes I did added it..@manoj, and yeah its been properly referenced to...

Comment: Are you able to view other labels?

Answer (score 0):

Your segmented control should be showing up regardless of whether you actually have it connected correctly or not. Can you see it in your .xib from when you dragged it out? If you have other UI is it possibly hiding underneath another view. If you show the detail view of your document window you can see the view hierarchy. Aside from this post a screenshot of your .xib if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Here is the screeshot..everything seems to be fine!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2359005/xib%20file.JPG

Comment: thanks a lot! I fixed it! it was out of bounds from the view!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Xcode you are using, but I often had a similar problem with Xcode 3.2 and the separate Interface Builder. It happened when I hadn't properly saved the .nib file in IB. In Xcode 4, that doesn't happen to me anymore.